# CreateProcess hook to add CommandLine

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, createprocess

I have a project that was adding some specific flags (command lines) to Chrome browser, the problem is that I was doing this by creating a new Chrome shortcut, with the flags I want to execute.

In the last days this solution became too superficial, and I was requested to do something more 'deeper'. Looking on Windows Registry, I didn't found any good solution to **always** add this flags when someone run Chrome, so I started thinking to hook [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) into explorer, and check if the process that is about to run is Chrome, then I add the flags in the lpCommandLine attribute.

I know hook into explorer is a pretty 'intrusive' solution, but this became helpful because I have some other achieves I was putting off on this project, and hooking will help me to get all them done.

I got the hook working, I tried by many ways to add the command lines when chrome is found, but no success... Right now (and I tried at least 8 different solutions) my detour function is:

```
function InterceptCreateProcess(lpApplicationName: PChar;
            lpCommandLine: PChar;
            lpProcessAttributes, lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
            bInheritHandles: BOOL;
            dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
            lpEnvironment: Pointer;
            lpCurrentDirectory: PChar;
            const lpStartupInfo: STARTUPINFO;
            var lpProcessInformation: PROCESS_INFORMATION): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Cmd: string;
begin
  Result:= CreateProcessNext(lpApplicationName,
          lpCommandLine,
          lpProcessAttributes,
          lpThreadAttributes,
          bInheritHandles,
          dwCreationFlags,
          lpEnvironment,
          lpCurrentDirectory,
          lpStartupInfo,
          lpProcessInformation);
  if (POS(Chrome, UpperCase(String(lpApplicationName))) > 0) then
  begin
    Cmd:= ' --show-fps-counter';
    lpCommandLine:= PChar(WideString(lpCommandLine + Cmd));
    ShowMessage(lpCommandLine);
  end;
end;
```

The "--show-fps-counter" is the command line I'm trying to add without success.

My Delphi version is XE4.

Comment: You haven't described how this fails. What debugging did you do? What do you expect to happen? What does happen?

Comment: This feels to me like using a cannon to shoot down flies - isn't there an API for Chrome where you can enable this feature via code?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError , I don't any API, at least I didn't discover this so far... Anyway, is like I said, I have some other goals that hook will help me to get done, this is why I thought it could be interesting to use...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't debugged, because like I said it's injected into explorer... I just tried this same code on a stand-alone exe and it worked. I get the chrome openned successfully, and the showmessage appears too. I post this question because I believed that the problem is something related with string issue (unicode), or anything like this. What I want to happen is to chrome show an FPS counter (this is what happens when you open it with the show-fps-counter command line), but it just opens without the counter.

Comment: I agree with @500. If the FPS counter can be enabled permanently in flag settings, then it's stored in some config as well (registry ?). I guess that this way won't do it anymore forceful as I think that even if you start Chrome with this parameter, you'll be still able to close that meter (e.g. via those flag settings).

Comment: Please do some debugging. You'll need to learn how. Trace debugging. OutputDebugString for instance.

Comment: Ok thank you all for the comments here... If anyone get a clue about what's going on, I'll try the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You're obviously seeking to do this for development work (because no end user would abide this apparent takeover of browser settings). I assume you're developing some kind of Chrome plug-in, and you want to make sure you don't degrade performance too much. Your idea is *not* the right solution for ensuring you have a consistent development environment. The right solution is simply to set the option on the `chrome://flags/` page.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is a pretty obvious thing... I need to add the parameter BEFORE calling the CreateProcessNext (original function)!
So, simply doing:

```
 if (POS(Chrome, UpperCase(String(lpApplicationName))) > 0) then
  begin
    lpCommandLine:= PChar(lpCommandLine + ' --show-fps-counter');
  end;
  Result:= CreateProcessNext(lpApplicationName,
          lpCommandLine,
          lpProcessAttributes,
          lpThreadAttributes,
          bInheritHandles,
          dwCreationFlags,
          lpEnvironment,
          lpCurrentDirectory,
          lpStartupInfo,
          lpProcessInformation);
```

works... note that I just inverted the order to change the lpCommandLine. Thank's for all participants and I'll still consider what was said here.

Comment: Which technology do you use for adding the hook? Where can I read more about it?